# Cateogries with exactly two morphisms between objects

Tags: category-theory

Is there a name for or a body of work about categories for which there are exactly two morphisms  $f,g$ between any two objects $X,Y$?  This is disrgarding self maps for which there is only the identity.

$$f: X \rightarrow Y$$
$$g: Y \rightarrow X$$

Another way to put it is "there is only one arrow in any one direction", where a direction is given $[A,B]$ a list which has a first and then a second element and the direction is first to second.

Comment: If there are only the identities $\operatorname{id}_X$ and $\operatorname{id}_Y$ in $\operatorname{End}(X)=\operatorname{Hom}(X,X)$ and $\operatorname{End}(Y)=\operatorname{Hom}(Y,Y)$ respectively, then $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$ and $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_Y$, so the two objects are isomorphic. The category with two elements and two non-trivial parallel arrows is more interesting, as equalizers and coequalizers are limits and colimits respectively of diagrams from that category.

Answer (score 4):

A category $C$ is called [indiscrete/chaotic/codiscrete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indiscrete+category) when, for each pair of objects $x, y \in C$, the hom-class $C(x, y)$ has exactly one element.

Note that, as a structure in its own right, an indiscrete category is equivalent to a set (the morphisms carry no information, because they are uniquely determined). However, indiscrete categories can be useful tools in studying other concepts. For instance, [a category enriched in a bicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+enriched+in+a+bicategory) is a lax functor from an indiscrete category.